# Secular Holidays Conundrum

Tags: relationships, holidays, religion

My coworkers are doing Halloween and Christmas at work, I'm a Messianic Jew, how do I avoid ruining my relationship with them?

Comment: We'd need more info to answer this. This is very vague. Why are you concerned about your relationship being "ruined"? What did you do, or what have they done, to damage the relationship between you and your coworkers?

Comment: Just ignore them. I don't celebrate halloween (or christmas, or birthdays, or solstices), and it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but aren't Messianic Jews followers of Jesus? What's the problem with Christmas?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you find them offensive or something? It seems unlikely that you need to attend a church service

Comment: Maybe related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34100/december-25-greetings

Comment: Also, I’m just going to leave this here. https://www.baltimoresun.com/news/bs-xpm-1991-08-06-9113008117-story.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Participate to the extent that your faith allows you.

Ask your Rabbi for guidance on this.  You can stick to your faith without being a disruption.  Return greetings for greetings, "Happy Halloween" with similar, and likewise with other greetings for other holidays.  Again, make sure, through your rabbi, that this does not violate your faith.

Show respect, and most people will reciprocate.  If anyone pushes back with "C'mon, get into the spirit" or something similar, you can politely reply with.

"I am having a good time, thank you.  Please, enjoy yourself."

Most people are very understanding.

Comment: In this case it isn't a big deal **unless you make it one**.

Comment: @MisterPositive yes, we actually ***CAN** all get along.  I've worked for many multinational companies.  Currently, I work with people from about 20 different nations, six different religions, and numerous ethnicities

Comment: I agree sir, and voted for your answer!

Comment: This is a good answer, since in the end we are literally all the same, humans who all deserve to be happy (Today or on Thursday).

Comment: @Donald I have been in very diverse environments.  Most people don't get involved in ingroup/outgroup dynamics unless you make a point to do so yourself.  A little respect goes a long way

Answer (score 18):

> My coworkers are doing Halloween and Christmas at work, I'm a
>   Messianic Jew, how do I avoid ruining my relationship with them?

Say nothing. Do nothing. Conduct yourself as you normally would.

If someone says "Happy Halloween" or "Merry Christmas" to you, respond with a simple "Thank you." or "Thank you, and the same to you."

Acknowledging a holiday, belief, or custom that you don't believe or participate in is polite and respectful. I don't have to be Jewish to say “Shanah tovah” to a Jewish coworker or friend, and it doesn't imply that I believe or participate in Rosh Hashanah. There's nothing wrong with replying in kind to someone's well wishes or holiday greetings.

If someone says "Merry Christmas" to me I reply "Merry Christmas to you." If someone says "Happy Hanukkah" to me I reply "Happy Hanukkah to you." That doesn't mean that I believe or participate in either one, it implies that I recognize and respect their beliefs and customs.